# DataJpaTest with a single autowired tested bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

I would like to create a test, which targets exactly one service class (`@Service`) in my project.

My service class has two kinds of dependencies:

- other services, which I want to mock with a `@MockBean`
- JPA repositories, which I do not want to mock; I want them to be real Spring beans, configured against H2 database

My services only depend on other services or repositories. Repositories have no dependencies - imagine JPA repository interfaces.

I have come up with following solution, which works fine:

```
@DataJpaTest
class FooServiceTests {

    @Autowired
    private FooRepository fooRepository;

    @MockBean
    private BarService barService;

    @Test
    void testService() {
        FooService fooService = new FooService(barService, fooRepository);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(barService);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(fooRepository);
    }

}
```

My question is, whether there is an alternative to this solution, which does not require manual assembly of the tested bean. A solution, which would have Spring assemble the bean for me, by using mocked services and real (H2) repositories. A solution, which allows tested bean to have dependencies `@Autowired` into private fields. Something like this: (which obviously does not work):

```
@DataJpaTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = FooService.class)
class FooService2Tests {

    @MockBean
    private BarService barService;

    @Autowired
    private FooService fooService;

    @Test
    void testService() {
        Assertions.assertNotNull(fooService);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(barService);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(fooService.getBarService());
        Assertions.assertNotNull(fooService.getFooRepository());
    }

}
```

I wanted to avoid using `@SpringBootTest`. If some answer suggests so, than it should explain, why that is the best way on how to go.

Comment: _which obviously does not work_  - @ygor in general your expected example looks correct, except `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class` on class annotation, and not sure that you are correct of usage of `ContextConfiguration` (**classes** - awaiting `@Configuration` prepared). What is the error you are now faced ?